# Can I create a div to display web content from another website?

Tags: html

Let's say my homepage is www.example.com and I want to add a div on it. When people visit my page, I want to show the content from www.google.com within the div.

When visitor clicked any link on www.google.com, it redirects user all within the div. Is it possible to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the element you are looking for is an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), which does about exactly what you ask.
There's a mayor downsite to this: This is bad for seo, you don't get points for the content in the iframe.
*Also, you can't Iframe Google, they don't allow you to. Other sites will work.*

---

The default styling of an iframe is a bit (well, a lot) ugly, so with some basic styling it will look more like the "div-look":

```
iframe{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000; /* Can be [none] too */
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could grab the contents of the other page/site and load it into the div.

1. Dynamic creation (serverside language)
2. Ajax creation (using javascript and a your serverside language)

You can now use something like PHP's `file_get_contents("the-web-page-url")` to load the content into a div

Comment: serverside will not work, the links found will link to the original page. You could counter this by prefixing all anchors with 'openViaMySite.php?url=example.com`, but that is a disaster waiting to happen (think of the exploit possibilities!)

Comment: So grab it into a variable and run a preg_match_all on it. Convert all absolute to relative or remove anchors entirely

Comment: Please promise me you dont do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: BTW, that makes it even worse! I just build a endlessloop with a file_get_contents on `yoursite.com/getPage.php?url=example.com` which will crash your server even faster

Comment: @Martijn It's purely a technique, not something you "have to do"

Comment: Yes and a dangerous one, of which the downsides should be mentioned, so any that anyone who might consider this base their solution on the complete picture.

Comment: We should also mention that `using another website's content` is a dangerous one ;)